# Setting the root for relative file paths in JUnit, AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, junit

I have some code that references a filename.  On the server, this reference is relative to my `war` directory.  When I'm running tests, though, the relative root doesn't seem to be set - only absolute paths, starting at the root of my local HD, actually find the files.

I'm testing in the context of an AppEngine `LocalServiceTestHelper`, which returns my war directory in its `getAppDir` method, but still the code can't understand the relative path.

How can I set the root for relative filenames in JUnit tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of options. In any case, I'd encapsulate the file access (or at least the file path resolution) in a separate class. That way, you could:

- Mock that class in your tests to provide the correct file (path)
- Pass an environment variable to your test class to resolve the correct file (path)
- Provide a fallback implementation if the file is not found (as it is the case in your tests)
- etc...

Answer (score 0):

For my unit tests, I created a utility class called [SupportFilePathResolver](http://pastebin.com/kvyjbstY) (see the code).  It finds the file by looking in the classpath. This works nicely if the files you care about are in the classpath. If not in the classpath, then this won't help you.